# Looking for a location on the Portuguese coast to surf

Tags: portugal, water-sports

Is there somewhere along the northern area Minho coastal area, near Vigo north of Porto in Portugal suitable for surfing?

I'm looking to stay somewhere near mountains with coast for surfing and at least a restaurant / bar.

Comment: What about [Nazaré](http://www.theinertia.com/surf/carlos-burle-sets-potential-new-world-record-at-maxed-out-nazare/)?

Comment: The northern coast isn't the best for surfing. Best surf spots would be Peniche, Nazaré, Ericeira, etc. You may want to consider going somewhere around *Parque Natural da Arrábida*, too.

Comment: I don't see any question here.